# Selenium return me a number?

Tags: python, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I just started to use selenium but I have a problem, probably answer is so simple but I couldn't find it anywhere. When I write a code to find an element like this :

```
options = Options()

options.binary_location="C:\ProgramFiles\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options,executable_path=r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\chromedriver")

driver.get("https://eksisozluk.com/galatasaray--33210")

comments = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.content')

time.sleep(10)

for comment in comments:
    print(comment.text)
```

I get a result like :

> 'dict' object has no attribute 'text'

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Your question is not clear, `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "content")` what exactly you wanna do with the web element? How does it look in UI ? Can you share relevant HTML ?

Comment: ı want to get a text of element ı tried :'find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"content").text but ı get an error like :error :list' object has no attribute 'text'.İf you can help me ı would be glad thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`driver.find_element` method returns a web element object. Actually it is a pointer to actual web element on the web page.
In case you want to get the element text you have to apply the corresponding method on the received web element. Something like this:

```py
the_element_text = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, element_class_name).text
```

**UPD**
In case of multiple web elements you can get the list of all the relevant elements and then iterate over that list extracting their texts, something like this:

```py
comments = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.content')
for comment in comments:
    print(comment.text)
```

Don't forget adding a wait before getting all these elements.

Comment: thanks for your reply but when ı tried :  driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"content").text  ı get:'   error :list' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Because you are using a wrong method! `find_elements` find element**s**. It returns a list of web elements, while you should use `find_element` method to get a **single** web element

Comment: What should ı do if ı want to get all elements as a text ?

Comment: And also tried with find_element ı get this:'dict' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Can you share a link to that page and describe what element / text are you trying to get?

Comment: ı am trying to take comments of some website forum: https://eksisozluk.com/galatasaray--33210      elements="content"

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
comments = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.content')
time.sleep(10)

for comment in comments:
    print(comment.text)                                                                                                                   result:                                                                                                                                       'dict' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Can you update the question with all your code? I see no reason why `comment` in my code will be dictionary

Comment: thanks for your effort and attention ı update my question with my all code thanks

Comment: That's very strange... Try putting the `time.sleep(10)` before `comments = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.content')`, not after it

Comment: İt didnt work but thx s